# Python Nested Loop Format

Tags: python, exception, nested-loops

I'm using the following code to scrap data from Yahoo! Finance, however, a modification I made to the first exception statement is causing the code to loop...nothing is being written to the CSV file at all. Currently, I am working through a debugger for this error. The errors I think are being caused in the while loop.

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import re
import urllib
from urllib2 import HTTPError
# import modules

symbolfile = open("symbols.txt")
symbolslist = symbolfile.read()
newsymbolslist = symbolslist.split("\n")

i = 0

f = csv.writer(open("pe_ratio.csv","wb"))
# short cut to write

f.writerow(["Name","PE","Revenue % Quarterly","ROA% YOY","Operating Cashflow","Debt to Equity"])
#first write row statement

# define name_company as the following
while i<len(newsymbolslist):
    try:
        page = urllib2.urlopen("http://finance.yahoo.com/q/ks?s="+newsymbolslist[i] +"%20Key%20Statistics").read()
    except urllib2.HTTPError:
        continue
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
        name_company = soup.findAll("div", {"class" : "title"}) 
        for name in name_company: #add multiple iterations?        
            all_data = soup.findAll('td', "yfnc_tabledata1")
            stock_name = name.find('h2').string #find company's name in name_company with h2 tag
            try:    
                f.writerow([stock_name, all_data[2].getText(),all_data[17].getText(),all_data[13].getText(), all_data[29].getText(),all_data[26].getText()]) #write down PE data
            except (IndexError, HTTPError) as e:
                pass
            i+=1
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Is this your actual indentation? Hint: any code appearing after a `continue` statement, at the same level of indentation, will never execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting i = i + 1 one indent earlier, so it is outside the separate for loop? I'd also put the indentation of the code after "continue" on the same line as try and except, otherwise it will only run in the except case (or be passed entirely because of continue).

```
while i<len(newsymbolslist):
    try:
        page = urllib2.urlopen("http://finance.yahoo.com/q/ks?s="+newsymbolslist[i] +"%20Key%20Statistics").read()
    except urllib2.HTTPError:
        continue
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
    name_company = soup.findAll("div", {"class" : "title"}) 
    for name in name_company: #add multiple iterations?        
        all_data = soup.findAll('td', "yfnc_tabledata1")
        stock_name = name.find('h2').string #find company's name in name_company with h2 tag
        try:    
            f.writerow([stock_name, all_data[2].getText(),all_data[17].getText(),all_data[13].getText(), all_data[29].getText(),all_data[26].getText()]) #write down PE data
        except (IndexError, HTTPError) as e:
            pass
    i+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the indentation is wrong. Try this:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import re
import urllib
from urllib2 import HTTPError
# import modules

symbolfile = open("symbols.txt")
symbolslist = symbolfile.read()
newsymbolslist = symbolslist.split("\n")

i = 0

f = csv.writer(open("pe_ratio.csv","wb"))
# short cut to write

f.writerow(["Name","PE","Revenue % Quarterly","ROA% YOY","Operating Cashflow","Debt to Equity"])
#first write row statement

# define name_company as the following
while i<len(newsymbolslist):
    try:
        page = urllib2.urlopen("http://finance.yahoo.com/q/ks?s="+newsymbolslist[i] +"%20Key%20Statistics").read()
    except urllib2.HTTPError:
        continue
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
    name_company = soup.findAll("div", {"class" : "title"}) 
    for name in name_company: #add multiple iterations?        
        all_data = soup.findAll('td', "yfnc_tabledata1")
        stock_name = name.find('h2').string #find company's name in name_company with h2 tag
        try:    
            f.writerow([stock_name, all_data[2].getText(),all_data[17].getText(),all_data[13].getText(), all_data[29].getText(),all_data[26].getText()]) #write down PE data
        except (IndexError, HTTPError) as e:
            pass
    i+=1
```